# Simple Responsive Layout with carousel strap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to come up with a responsive layout and seem to be going round in circles!  Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial or some examples to try and achieve this...

[image]

The center strap is going to be used for a horizontal carousel and will have a maximum height of 500px.  The logo and footer are going to be 100px each.

When viewed on a tablet or mobile I just want it to look as it does on the desktop with the logo and footer visible with the central strap made smaller to fit.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) - they've got some pretty easy to use stylings which will help you design your website as you'd liked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that is actually pretty simple to achieve!

Checkout this quick codepen I put together: http://codepen.io/seanwash/pen/eKjnz/

Basically, you can set a max-height on the slider's container to make sure that it's never taller than 500px. By setting `max-width: 100%` on the image we make sure that the slider will scale down as the browser shrinks.

For the responsive slider, I'd check out something like http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ as it's responsive out of the box. I've used Flexslider myself more than a few times and it always works great!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to pen that example but it doesn't work. Resize it and see

Comment: Are you referring to how in the pen the image doesn't expand to fill the container when the container is wider than the image? If that's the case, that can be handled by the slider plugin, or with some small css tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make a slider yourself and just use it out of the box then iview and flex slider and many others work.